# Inconsistencies in RDP connections to similar servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, ubuntu-14.04

We have a bunch of Windows 2008R2 servers used as RDP servers that are (or at least should be) essentially identical in configuration (and are arranged in a RDP farm).
When administrating from home, I use remmina on Ubuntu. For unknown reason, there is *one* server among these that I *cannot* connect to from home unless I use *different* client-side settings. So apparently there are server-side differences, but I'm unable to find them and would like to ask what I could be missing.

Specifically, I can connect to all servers (but one) with the following remmina settings (under *advanced*):

- Quality: low (fast)
- Sound: Off
- Security: Negotiate
- connect to console: checked

For the problematic host, I need to adjust the client-side setting to either *TLS* or *RDP*. I cannot use *NLA* or *Negotiate*.

Here are the server-side settings that I consider relevant (Properties of the connection, "general" tab) and are identical between "good" servers and the "bad" one:

- Security: Negotiate
- Encryption: Client compatible
- Accept connections only from computers with Network level Authentication: NOT(!) checked
- Certificate: (issued by our internal CA)

Who can explain the difference?

Comment: Check the problematic server's event logs when your login attempt fails, it may give you a clue on what's wrong.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I see no relevant entry whatsoever

Comment: Erase ~/.freerdp/known_hosts and retry. You forget to tell if you got the same symptom if you connect from a windows host

Comment: Found similar question http://serverfault.com/questions/83884/require-tls-on-rdp-for-all-connections . Does it help?

Comment: Under the "Remote" tab in System Properties are all servers configured the same; i.e. "Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop (less secure)" vs "Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication (more secure)?

Answer (score 0):

From the start menu, pick administrative tools, remote desktop services and then remote desktop session host configuration.

In that window there's a Connections panel with all of your network interfaces listed.  Double click on the connection that you're accessing and check the settings on the general tab.

Confirm this is the same as you expect and the same as your other servers.

Comment: I already said that the settings under properties of the connection were identical. However, this problem of January has been solved long ago, though I am unsure what the solution was back then - otherwise I might post that as answer.